# Tumblr Theme Permalink Footer Positioning Problems?

Tags: html, css

Alright, so I'm making a Tumblr theme, which is currently live [here](http://comehereking.tumblr.com/)
and I am having difficulty positioning the footer (which currently only consists of a div, containing a link to the archive). The list of notes just goes underneath it, and it sits where it would without giving a thought to the list of notes that is *obviously* sitting there (rude.)

I want to just edit the div itself in this bit

```
    <style>{block:PermalinkPage}#footer {}{/block:PermalinkPage}</style>
```

but I'm not sure how, and the positioning seems to register strangely and I'm not entirely sure why. Or, perhaps setting the original footer to display:none in the permalink block, and creating a separate one that only appears in the permalink pages, but if it won't be positioned right what's the point in that either?

Anyone have any suggestions? Any help? My brain is fried. (I know this is probably really simple, and not worth having my brain fried over, I mean it's just HTML/CSS but I'm new at learning this so that's 90% of why I'm struggling with  this in the first place probably)

Comment: You're talking about the container that holds your Next >> Archive pagination right?  On my browser it scrolls with the window, the list never goes underneath it. (Chrome)

Comment: Mine doesn't do that. It just sits directly on top of the notes, and stays there. I don't want that. I want it to sit where I tell it to sit and it's not doing that.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

*This isn't an answer, just need to post some pics to help trouble-shoot.*

Everything looks fine on my mac too... here's a few screenshots to make sure we're talking about the same thing.

**scrolled to bottom:**

[image]

**slightly scrolled up:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your helpful efforts, it's just on the permalink pages for individual posts.